# Imgur medium images with too much compression

Tags: feature-request, imgur

If we append `m` (or `s`) to our uploaded images file names, we get the medium (and small) versions. I noticed quite some artifacts in the medium sized.

## Original

<sup>`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pOz.png`</sup>

[image: original image]

## Medium

(artifacts on white on blue, white on purple, and blue/purple edges, blurred text)

<sup>`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pOzm.png`</sup>

[image: medium image]

## Small

(could be crispier)

<sup>`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pOzs.png`</sup>

[image: small image]

Is it possible to increase the quality of the compression for the intermediate sizes?
Having those options is great to shorten the post length. But the quality is bellow what I would publish on the web.

Comment: This question is on-topic because Stack Exchange does not use the commodity Imgur offering, they have a custom configuration and have had specific changes made to accommodate them before. This is not outside the scope of something that Stack Exchange could potentially have changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Use the `<img>` tag.

**Medium**:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pOz.png" width="320" />
```

[image]

**Small**:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8pOz.png" width="90" />
```

[image]