# When embedding image, making it small without making it blurry or keep the original?

Tags: support, images, image-size-modifiers

If I paste a copied-screenshot in the clipboard, often the image is too big. I know I can append letters like `l` or `m`, to make it small, but then it becomes blurry, and clicking the small image does not show the original, full-size image. So, both choices seem bad.

Is there a way to make the pasted image appear small in the post but make it less blurry, or make the full-size image appear when the small image is clicked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imgur medium images with too much compression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/imgur-medium-images-with-too-much-compression) (yes there is a way)

Comment: It would be nice if the answer here could be migrated to the other question, as it is a very common solution (and less work to implement).

Comment: The first dupe listed is a data waster, using imgur m is much more efficient

Comment: Maybe if you view the oage on a small phone. But I mostly view this site on a high-definition monitor, and I don't think it is waste of data yo display high resolution images in a small logical size.

Comment: I see the dupes have changed listed order since I posted my comment - the `<img>` tag is the data waster. By definition it wastes data, because it draws smaller than the image's actual dimensions, whilst still forcing the entire file to be downloaded. That's precisely why we have the `m` option [& a slew of other sizes too] with full size on click through. Using `<img>` is just a hack, & the image is never going to draw bigger than about 700px anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: screenshot of question]

Being blurry is fine. Click to view the large image can be done like so:

```
[![screenshot of question][small]][large]

  [small]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwJH9s.png
  [large]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwJH9.png
```

Destructure:

When you insert an image two markdown concepts are being generated:

- an image (`<img src="">`) : `![][image]`
- an anchor (`<a href="">html</a>`) : `[Inner html for the link][image]`

The link encloses the image:

```
[![][image]][image]
```

where both the image src and the href share the same URL reference. You can copy the reference and give it a new unique name to have a click on the image do different things. One option is to open the full size image but you can link to anywhere. I sometimes use it to link to a SEDE query when I only have a screenshot of the data.

Comment: I wish it automatically worked this way (large image automatically becomes smaller, and the original image gets shown when the small image is clicked) by default without users' having to remember this code, unless the user specifically opt out.

Comment: It's slightly easier if you let SE's own 'engine' do the numbering. It will automatically add two numbered links in a row, sequentially `[1][1]` for the first inlined image `[2][2]` for the second & so on…  so you make those into `[1][11]` & `[2][12]` which saves a lot of *thinking* ;) Copy/paste the link line at the bottom, add your `s` or `m` etc to each first line & add a `1` to each second line. Not exactly 'instant' but not exactly rocket science. See my answer in the [linked duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385664/276027) for a more graphical view of this explanation.